# ASP.Net Web Api Identity Access Token... Where to store?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I'm making use of Identity for my Web API. I am successfully able to retrieve an access token by providing the username and password, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with it afterwards. I am thinking about storing it in a cookie, but I'm not sure whether or not this is bad practice. If it is, what would be better alternatives to this solution.

I don't want to let a user login every time he visits the website, so because of that I'm looking for ways of storing the access token. I have been searching the web (and SO) for solutions to this problem, but did not find a suitable answer. I found the following question that's similar, but did not get an answer: [Where to store OAUTH2 access token in mvc5 web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280941/where-to-store-oauth2-access-token-in-mvc5-web-app).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: You might find more success finding an answer if you expand your search so it's less MVC-centric: "OAuth2 storing access tokens". There's some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280827/using-oauth2-in-html5-web-app) and [on another S.E. site](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2). Also, you may need to specify 1) which [grant type](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4) you're using 2) who's auth server and where it exists 3) lifetime of access and refresh tokens

Comment: Thanks for the links, those are useful!